# ansible-container build error - dockers

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, ansible

I am working on ansible container example as mentioned in http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/getting_started.html and getting error while doing ansible-container build.

Container Type is dockers.

I am new to Ansible containers module and any help is much appreciated. Thank you!!

```
[user@hostname hello-world]$ sudo pip install ansible-container[docker]
Collecting ansible-container[docker]
  Using cached ansible-container-0.9.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.9 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=6.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.12 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.yaml>=0.14.2 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: structlog[dev]>=16.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible-container[docker])
# These are the python requirements for your Ansible Container builder.
Requirement already satisfied: docker>=2.4.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.9->ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2->ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2->ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2->ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2->ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.ordereddict; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and python_version <= "2.7" in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from ruamel.yaml>=0.14.2->ans
ible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; extra == "dev" in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from structlog[dev]>=16.1->ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: backports.ssl-match-hostname>=3.5; python_version < "3.5" in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker>=2.4.0->ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress>=1.0.16; python_version < "3.3" in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker>=2.4.0->ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: docker-pycreds>=0.2.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker>=2.4.0->ansible-container[docker])
Requirement already satisfied: websocket-client>=0.32.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker>=2.4.0->ansible-container[docker])
Installing collected packages: ansible-container
  Running setup.py install for ansible-container ... done
Successfully installed ansible-container-0.9.2
[user@ hello-world]$

[user@hostname hello-world]$ ls -alrt
    total 40
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 user user  144 Mar 31 00:28 ansible.cfg
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 user user 1181 Mar 31 00:28 meta.yml
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 user user  298 Mar 31 00:28 requirements.yml
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 user user   31 Mar 31 00:29 requirements.txt
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 user user  108 Mar 31 00:29 helloworld.py
    drwxrwxr-x.  3 user user   18 Mar 31 00:33 roles
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 user user 2706 Mar 31 00:35 container.yml
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 user user  130 Mar 31 00:59 ansible-requirements.txt
    drwx------. 12 user user 4096 Mar 31 00:59 ..
    drwxrwxr-x.  3 user user 4096 Mar 31 01:00 .
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 user user   78 Mar 31 01:00 =36.2.7
    [user@hostname hello-world]$ 

[user@hostname hello-world]$ sudo ansible-container build
ERROR   Unknown exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/container/cli.py", line 299, in __call__
    getattr(core, u'hostcmd_{}'.format(args.subcommand))(**vars(args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/container/__init__.py", line 28, in __wrapped__
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/container/core.py", line 156, in hostcmd_build
    config['services'], **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/container/utils/loader.py", line 16, in load_engine
    package='container')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/container/docker/engine.py", line 51, in <module>
    container.__version__
ImportError: You must install Ansible Container with Docker(tm) support. Try:
pip install ansible-container[docker]==0.9.2
[user@sudo hello-world]$
```

Comment: I fixed the problem by installing latest ansible container from source.

[user@hostname ~]$ sudo git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible-container.git
[user@hostname ~]$ cd ansible-container
[user@hostname ansible-container]$ sudo pip install -e .[docker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `virtualenv`.

Take a look here for a full sample. First, install virtualenv and ansible inside it

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install ansible
$ pip install ansible-container[docker]
$ pip install docker==2.7.0
```

Then, clone the sample and build it

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mkowsiak/ansible-with-big-file.git
$ cd ansible-with-big-file
$ git checkout smaller-file-that-works
$ ansible-container build
```